# Crawl Error: The first attempt to crawl this object failed

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a newly installed SharePoint 2013 farm (one SP server), and I get a whole lot of errors (90%) in the crawl log. Have anyone any idea about these errors:

The first attempt to crawl this object failed. Another attempt is being made.

> ( Failed to retieve blob from URI \\gthrsvc_49c40646-05c9-4963-8ccb-9500f1aff56a-crawl-0\6c\0x46c.;
>   ; SearchID = F622A41B-2CEC-4CAE-9C43-D83065AF2A34 )

I have not found anything strange in the log files either. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

**Note:**

*I made crawl with full control permission user.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what kind of information you want?